# C# regex - find one or more matches for a single pattern inside parentheses

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-group

I have the following string:

```
(someMethod("SomeString1"), someMethod("SomeString2. SomeString3"))
```

Required output is:

```
 1. Group 'method': someMethod ; Group 'key': SomeString1
 2. Group 'method': someMethod ; Group 'key': SomeString2. SomeString3
```

So far I have the following regex:

```
\((?<method>someMethod)\(\"(?<key>.*)\"\)\)
```

However it returns an incorrect result:

```
 1. Group 'method': someMethod ; Group 'key': SomeString1"), someMethod("SomeString2. SomeString3
```

How should I modify the regex to get the required output?

UPDATE: In the end, it should match the following:

```
someMethod("SomeString1") - No, should not match

(someMethod("SomeString1"), someMethod("SomeString2. SomeString3")) - Yes, two matches
```

Comment: Maybe `\b(?<method>someMethod)\("(?<key>.*?)"\)`? See https://regex101.com/r/nqDEkI/1

Answer (score 1):

To get multiple matches, you can repeat the part 1 or more times to get at least 2 matches and keep the same group names. Then you could get the matches from the [capture collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures?view=netcore-3.1).

```
\((?<method>someMethod)\("(?<key>.*?)"\)(?:,\s*(?<method>someMethod)\("(?<key>.*?)"\))+\)
```

[.Net regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%28%28%3f%3cmethod%3esomeMethod%29%5c%28%22%28%3f%3ckey%3e.*%3f%29%22%5c%29%28%3f%3a%2c%5cs*%28%3f%3cmethod%3esomeMethod%29%5c%28%22%28%3f%3ckey%3e.*%3f%29%22%5c%29%29%2b%5c%29&i=someMethod%28%22SomeString1%22%29+-+No%2c+should+not+match%0d%0a%0d%0a%28someMethod%28%22SomeString1%22%29%2c+someMethod%28%22SomeString2.+SomeString3%22%29%29+-+Yes%2c+two+matches%0d%0a%0d%0a%0d%0a%28someMethod%28%22SomeString1%22%29%2c+someMethod%28%22SomeString2.+SomeString3%22%29%2c+someMethod%28%22SomeString4.+SomeString5%22%29%29+-+hree+matches)

[image]

Comment: Thank you @The fourth bird, that was exactly what I needed! In the end had to modify it a bit in case I encounter the following strings: 
a) (someMethod("SomeString1"), someMethod("SomeString2"), someOtherMethod.someProperty)
b) (someMethod("SomeString1"))
c) (someMethod("SomeString1"), someOtherMethod.someProperty)

This is the regex I have in the end: 
\((?<method>someMethod)\("(?<key>.*?)"\)(?:,\s*(?<method>someMethod)\("(?<key>.*?)"\).*?)+\)|\((?<method>someMethod)\("(?<key>.*?)"\)